# Notification created from Service disappears from status bar

Tags: android, file-upload, android-service, android-notifications

I have a webservice and I am using `ksoap2` to connect to it and upload some pictures.

The process is:

1. Open the gallery
2. Select a few pictures
3. Share to my app
4. Start a foreground service
5. send the basic information to this service, like an array with all the picture's path
6. handle the intent and take the bundles
7. and start the foreground notification with the proper flag and with startForeground(id,noty)

**The problem:**
  Everything goes right. Uploading and showing the items uploaded ...until...suddenly the notification just disappear from the bar.

After a while it shows by itself again and continues the upload, I tried to set some stuff to get the last item uploaded and start from there, I don't know if I am doing right and I would like to have an advice about this.

**This is the Activity from where I call the Service:**

```
 Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, UploadService.class);

        Bundle bund = new Bundle();
        bund.putStringArray("pathList", pictureList);
        bund.putString("tags", tag);
        boolean hasGeotag = UserManagerClass.UserLogged.isActiveLocation();
        bund.putBoolean("hasGeotag", hasGeotag);
        if (hasGeotag) {
            GeoTag gtag = UserManagerClass.UserLocation;
            bund.putDouble("latitude", gtag.getLatitude());
            bund.putDouble("longitude", gtag.getLongitude());
            bund.putString("city", gtag.getCity());
            bund.putString("country", gtag.getCountry());
            bund.putString("address", gtag.getAddress());

        }
        bund.putInt("idOwner", IDOWNER);
        bund.putInt("idUser", UserManagerClass.UserLogged.getID());
        bund.putInt("albumindex", albumIndex);
        bund.putInt("privacyindex", privacyIndex);
        bund.putString("comment", comment);

        mServiceIntent.putExtras(bund);

        startService(mServiceIntent);
```

**and this is the code of the Service:**

```
public class UploadService extends Service {

private static final int myID = 1433;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "SERVICEUPLOAD";

private static final String UPLOADED_PATH = "UPLOADED_";

private static int position;

private int albumIndex;

private String comment;

private boolean hasGeotag;

private int idOwner;

private int idUser;

private GeoTag location;

private String[] pathList;

private int privacyIndex;

private SoapPost sp;

private String tags;

private NotificationManager nManager;

private PendingIntent pi;


@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.e("step 1", "entered to create");
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

}

private void exit() {

    Log.e("step 10", "ending...");
    deletePosition();
    Log.e("step 12", "ended");
    this.stopForeground(true);
    updateNotification(true);
}

void createNotification() {

    Log.e("step 4", "entered to create notification");
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the
    // expanded notification
    CharSequence text = getText(R.string.upload_waiting);
    //
    pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.add_comment_icon);
    builder.setTicker(text);
    builder.setContentIntent(pi);
    builder.setContentText(text);
    builder.setContentTitle(text);

    startForeground(myID, builder.build());
}

private void updateNotification(boolean completed) {

    Log.e("step 8", "updating notification");
    String ticker = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.upload_uploading_tick), position);
    String message = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.upload_uploading_message_progress), position, pathList.length);
    String title = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.upload_uploading_title), position);
    String title_completed = getResources().getString(R.string.upload_uploading_title_completed);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.add_comment_icon);

    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setTicker(ticker);

    if (!completed)
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
    else {
        builder.setContentTitle(title_completed);
        pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);

    }

    builder.setContentIntent(pi);
    if (completed)
        nManager.notify(myID, builder.build());
    else
        startForeground(myID, builder.build());

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.e("step 2", "entered to onstart");
    handleIntent(intent);
    return START_STICKY;
}

void handleIntent(Intent data) {

    Log.e("step 3", "entered to handle");
    // GETS THE POSITIONS IF THE SERVICE WAS STOPPED BEFORE
    // RETURN 0 IF IT WASNT
    getPosition();
    //
    if (data == null)
        this.stopForeground(true);

    Bundle dt = data.getExtras();

    tags = dt.getString("tags");
    pathList = dt.getStringArray("pathList");
    hasGeotag = dt.getBoolean("hasGeotag");

    if (hasGeotag) {

        location = new GeoTag();
        location.setLatitude(dt.getDouble("latitude"));
        location.setLongitude(dt.getDouble("longitude"));
        location.setAddress(dt.getString("address"));
        location.setCity(dt.getString("city"));
        location.setCountry(dt.getString("country"));

    }
    idOwner = dt.getInt("idOwner");
    idUser = dt.getInt("idUser");
    albumIndex = dt.getInt("albumindex");
    privacyIndex = dt.getInt("privacyindex");
    comment = dt.getString("comment");
    // isCover = dt.getBoolean("isCover");
    sp = new SoapPost();

    // CREATES THE NOTFICATION
    createNotification();
    // FINALLY SEND THE DATA TO THE WEB SERVICE
    sendData();
}

private void sendData() {

    Log.e("step 4", "entered to send data");
    for (String fl : pathList) {
        Log.e("step 5", "sending... " + fl);
        if (fl != null && !fl.equals(UPLOADED_PATH)) {

            try {

                String[] dataup = new String[10];

                if (hasGeotag) {

                    dataup = new String[15];
                    dataup[10] = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                    dataup[11] = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                    dataup[12] = location.getAddress();
                    dataup[13] = location.getCity();
                    dataup[14] = location.getCountry();

                }

                if (comment.length() > 0)
                    dataup[0] = URLEncoder.encode(comment, "UTF-8");
                else
                    dataup[0] = "";

                dataup[1] = String.valueOf(idOwner);
                dataup[2] = String.valueOf(idUser);
                dataup[3] = "2";
                dataup[4] = "";
                dataup[5] = String.valueOf(albumIndex);
                dataup[6] = String.valueOf(privacyIndex);
                dataup[7] = "";
                dataup[8] = "";
                dataup[9] = "";

                File file = new File(fl);
                // CONTINUE ONLY IF THE FILE EXISTS
                if (file.exists()) {
                    Log.e("step 6", "file exists true");
                    // SETTING WIDTH AND HEIGHT
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fl, options);
                    int wth = options.outWidth;
                    int hth = options.outHeight;
                    long lenght = file.length();
                    // END W AND H
                    String b64 = null;
                    b64 = Base64.encodeToString(PictureManagerClass.getBytesFromFile(file), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    file = null;
                    // SETTING
                    // 4 BASE64
                    // 7 W
                    // 8 H
                    // 9 L
                    dataup[4] = b64;
                    dataup[7] = String.valueOf(wth);
                    dataup[8] = String.valueOf(hth);
                    dataup[9] = String.valueOf(lenght);
                    Log.e("step 7", "uploading... " + fl);
                    // SET THE CURRENT ITEM AS UPLOADED
                    pathList[position] = null;
                    // SAVE THE ACTUAL POSITION
                    savePosition();
                    sp.uploadPicture(dataup, tags, SoapPost.UPLOAD_PICTURE);

                    position++;
                    updateNotification(false);

                }// END FILE EXISTS

            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // SAVE THE ACTUAL POSITION
                savePosition();
                //
                StackTraceElement[] stack = ex.getStackTrace();
                String Trace = " ";
                for (StackTraceElement line : stack) {
                    Trace += line.toString();
                }
                Log.e("SERVICE: ", Trace);
            }

        }// END FL NULL

    }// END FOR
    exit();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    // SAVE THE ACTUAL POSITION
    savePosition();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

    // SAVE THE ACTUAL POSITION
    savePosition();
    super.onLowMemory();
}

void savePosition() {

    Log.e("step 9", "saving position");
    // SET THE VALUES FROM PATHS TO SET TO SAVE IT INTO PREFERENCES
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("position", position);
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    if (pathList != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++)
            pathList[i] = null;

        for (int i = position; i < pathList.length; i++)
            if (pathList[i] != null)
                set.add(pathList[i]);
    }

    if (pathList != null)
        editor.putStringSet("pathList", set);
    editor.commit();
}

void getPosition() {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    position = prefs.getInt("position", 0);
    Log.e("step 3.1", position + "");
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set = prefs.getStringSet("pathList", set);

    int pos = 0;
    for (String path : set) {
        pathList = new String[set.size()];
        pathList[pos] = path;
        pos++;
    }

}

void deletePosition() {

    Log.e("step 11", "clear...");
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Service#onBind(android.content.Intent)
 */
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

**FIXED**
i fixed it...this is the **new method sendData()**:

```
 private void sendData() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (String fl : pathList) {

                if (fl != null && !fl.equals(UPLOADED_PATH)) {

                    try {

                        String[] dataup = new String[10];

                        if (hasGeotag) {

                            dataup = new String[15];
                            dataup[10] = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                            dataup[11] = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                            dataup[12] = location.getAddress();
                            dataup[13] = location.getCity();
                            dataup[14] = location.getCountry();

                        }

                        if (comment.length() > 0)
                            dataup[0] = URLEncoder.encode(comment, "UTF-8");
                        else
                            dataup[0] = "";

                        dataup[1] = String.valueOf(idOwner);
                        dataup[2] = String.valueOf(idUser);
                        dataup[3] = "2";
                        dataup[4] = "";
                        dataup[5] = String.valueOf(albumIndex);
                        dataup[6] = String.valueOf(privacyIndex);
                        dataup[7] = "";
                        dataup[8] = "";
                        dataup[9] = "";

                        File file = new File(fl);
                        // CONTINUE ONLY IF THE FILE EXISTS
                        if (file.exists()) {

                            // SETTING WIDTH AND HEIGHT
                            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fl, options);
                            int wth = options.outWidth;
                            int hth = options.outHeight;
                            long lenght = file.length();
                            // END W AND H

                            byte[] pic = PictureManagerClass.getBytesFromFile(file);
                            Log.e("picLength", pic.length + "");
                            file = null;
                            // SETTING
                            // 4 BASE64
                            // 7 W
                            // 8 H
                            // 9 L
                            dataup[4] = "";
                            dataup[7] = String.valueOf(wth);
                            dataup[8] = String.valueOf(hth);
                            dataup[9] = String.valueOf(lenght);
                            Log.e("step 7", "uploading... " + fl);
                            // SET THE CURRENT ITEM AS UPLOADED
                            pathList[position] = null;
                            // SAVE THE ACTUAL POSITION
                            savePosition();
                            String mes = sp.uploadPicture(dataup, tags, SoapPost.UPLOAD_PICTURE, pic);
                            Log.e("picID", mes);
                            pic = null;
                            dataup = null;
                            position++;
                            updateNotification(false);

                            Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);

                        }// END FILE EXISTS

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {
                        // SAVE THE ACTUAL POSITION
                        savePosition();
                        //
                        StackTraceElement[] stack = ex.getStackTrace();
                        String Trace = " ";
                        for (StackTraceElement line : stack) {
                            Trace += line.toString();
                        }
                        Log.e("SERVICE: ", Trace);
                    }

                }// END FL NULL

            }// END FOR
            exit();

        }
    }).start();;

}
```

and now the notification doesnt hide until all files were uploaded ... thanks.